# Thrift Call in Camunda BPM Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries, thrift, camunda

Im trying to have a service task in my Camunda BPMN diagram, that makes a thrift call to my running apache thrift server. I sucessfully linked the corresponding java class to the service task and have confirmed, that it executes its code without any error, as long as no external libraries are referenced in that class.
But of course, to make a thrift call i had to import the Thrift libraries. I did this and eclipse doesn't show me any errors, but when i try to execute the process in Camunda, i get a ClassNotFoundException: apache/thrift/TTransport, which means it can't find the referenced TTransport class, that i used in my class to make the Thrift Call.

Can anyone tell me how i get the required libraries in my project, so Camunda can find them?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `try to execute the process in Camunda,` What do you mean with this statement? Do you use the tomcat distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it: My mistake was that i added the external libraries as jars to the build path, instead of adding them as maven dependencies to the pom.